# What is wrong with this PHP logging script?

Tags: php, logging

I get this error with this script

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in
>   /home/*******/public_html/data.php on line 2

Could someone help me with it please? Thanks guys!

```
<?php
if (! empty ($ _ GET ['c'])) {
  $ F = fopen ("log.txt", "a +");
  fwrite ($ f, $ _ GET ['c']);
  fclose ($ f);
}
?>
```

Comment: What's with the spaces in `$ _ GET` and between the `$` and variable names?

Comment: I'm not sure.......i took them out but it still does not work